# Instagram API pagination in PHP

Tags: php, json, instagram, instagram-api

I am trying to create a small instagram app in PHP only (no database) and without getting an `access_token` (just my client_id). So far so good, (i.e. input user_id returns photos from last 30 days, with likes-count and created_time, in a table), until I get to pagination. As expected, I want to hit a 'more' button which loads next json file and **adds additional photos to the existing table**, but it falls apart there... Here is what I've got, working, except for the pagination attempt.

NOTE: this is an internal app, so the sensitivity of my client_id is not an issue, if it is exposed

```
<?php
if (!empty($_GET['user_id'])){
  $user_id = ($_GET['user_id']);
  $instagram_url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/' . $user_id . '/media/recent/?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID';
  $instagram_json = file_get_contents($instagram_url);
  $instagram_array = json_decode($instagram_json, true);
    }
?>
```

...

```
    <?php
    if(!empty($instagram_array)){

        $instagram_array['pagination'] as $page { // Attempt at pagination
            echo '<p>' .$page['next_url'].'</p>'; // Attempt at pagination
        }  // Attempt at pagination

        foreach($instagram_array['data'] as $image){
            if ($image['created_time'] > strtotime('-30 days')) {
                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td>' . date('M d, Y', $image['created_time']) . '</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$image['likes']['count'].'</td>';
                echo '<td><img src="'.$image['images']['standard_resolution']['url'].'" alt=""/ style="max-height:40px"></td>';
                echo '</tr>';
        }
      }
    }
    ?>

  </body>
</html>
```

Note: this is cobbled together from a few other sources - I am a total noob, so please forgive me if I need a little hand-holding...:)

Answer (score 1):

You may specify min_timestamp to return medias which taken later than this timestamp

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user_id}/media/recent/?access_token={access_token}&min_timestamp={min_timestamp}
```

$instagram_array['pagination']['next_url'] should be removed, it may include your access token which is a sensible data, that must be always invisible.

**list_ig.php**

```
<?
$user_id = "...";
$access_token = "...";
//30 day ago
$min_timestamp = strtotime("-30 day",time());
//pagination feature
$next_max_id = $_GET['next_max_id'];

$instagram_url  = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/" . $user_id . "/media/recent/?access_token=" .$access_token. "&min_timestamp=" . $min_timestamp;
if($next_max_id != "")
    $instagram_url  .= "&max_id=" . $next_max_id;

$instagram_json  = file_get_contents($instagram_url);
$instagram_array  = json_decode($instagram_json ,true);
?>

<? if( $instagram_array['pagination']['next_max_id'] != "" ): ?>
<a href="list_ig.php?next_max_id=<?=$instagram_array['pagination']['next_max_id']?>">More</a>
<? endif;?>

.... print instagram data....
```

Instagram AJAX Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/ajhtLgzc/

Comment: actually, i am not getting access_tokens, and it's an internal app, so sensitivity of client_id is not an issue.

Comment: ok, so once I remove access_token and replace with client_id (and make a few other small tweaks), this is **soooo** close to what I want, but only thing that's missing is that I need the new photos to show up on the same page, so new loaded page will now show 40 images (20 original and 20 new) and next click will show 60 images, etc...

Comment: I totally want to upvote you for getting me this close, but can't do it because my rep is too low:(

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, You may use AJAX to load new photos on the same page, please refer my fiddle example.

Comment: No apology needed on the reply - you're helping me!! But, I am confused. Is this ajax meant to work _with_ the php above..., or instead of it? I need to get the like-count and created_date from json like before, and put the images into my table and I don't see how to do that with your ajax.

Comment: What do you say @Parfait? You've got two answers working most of the way, but I don't know how to put them together with each other? Your help is appreciated:)